# Can TortoiseGit use a repository of Google Cloud Source repositories?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, tortoisegit

I tried to log in to Clone a repository from Google Cloud Source repositories.
But the following message showed.

> Cloning into 'C:\Users\test'...
>
> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory error: cannot spawn
>   sh: No such file or directory fatal: remote error:
>
> Invalid authentication credentials.
>
> Please generate a new identifier:
>   https://source.developers.google.com/new-password
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

The site insits `git config --global http.cookiefile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitcookies"`
somehow , After executing above command, nothing happened.
Will It be able to use TortoiseGit on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone the Cloud Source Repository using `gcloud` like so:

`gcloud source repos clone [REPO_NAME] [LOCAL_DIRECTORY]`

See this [article](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-a-repository).

Once you have cloned the repository, you can use TortoiseGit on it. 
Hope this helps!